# SQL Query using CASE and combine rows

Tags: sql, xml, db2, xquery

This is the current output in the SQL Code:

```
Group     | USERLIST
Region 1  | <Users><USERID>ID1</USERID><USERID>ID2</USERID></Users>
Region 1  | <Users><USERID>ID3</USERID></Users>
Region 2  | <Users><USERID>ID4</USERID></Users>
```

I'd like the output to come out as this:

```
    Group     | USERLIST
Region 1  | <Users><USERID>ID1</USERID><USERID>ID2</USERID><USERID>ID3</USERID></Users>
Region 2  | <Users><USERID>ID4</USERID></Users>
```

Here's the current code I'm using.

```
SELECT CASE
  WHEN _ID LIKE '%REG1%' THEN 'Region 1'
  WHEN _ID LIKE '%REG2%' THEN 'Region 2'
  WHEN _ID LIKE '%REG3%' THEN 'Region 3'
  WHEN _ID LIKE '%REG4%' THEN 'Region 4'
  ELSE NULL
 END AS "Group"
 ,XMLSERIALIZE( 
  CONTENT XMLELEMENT( 
   NAME "Users",
   XMLAGG( 
    XMLELEMENT(NAME "USERID", _USERID) 
   )
  ) 
  AS CLOB(30K)
 ) AS "USERLIST"
```

The reason for using a LIKE operator is because the data being compared will have a format of xxxxREG#xxx. Where x represents differences in the data. Does anyone have an idea on how I can combine the duplicate groups into a single row?

Comment: XMLAGG?  CLOB?  This looks like an Oracle query.  You might want PLSQL tag rather than SQL-Server.

Comment: Fixed the tags. It's a query for DB2

Comment: Wait, what does your _current_ data look like?  What's actually in the table?  Shouldn't a regular `GROUP BY` be what you need?

Comment: The data looks like the first example above. _ID data is represented in the format xxxxREG#xxx. The x's can be anything else. So I'm doing a like operator to look specifically for REG#, where # is a number. If one user contains absREG1ghj and two other users contains aaaREG1ggg, it will create the two duplicate columns you see in the first example.

Comment: The actual data are user id's and app requests they are making based on the region they reside in.